# update choice-radio button column, within workflow

Tags: workflow, column

I’m having a SharePoint list, the list contains the following column

- Column name: initiator outcome, Column type: choice, radio buttons

First options(button):Cancel Request.
Second options(button): Request Update.

I operate workflow on this list items.
I want to implement the following scenario:

- If the user choose the first option --> the workflow ends
- If the user chooses the second options so--> the initiator outcome column becomes equal to zero.

How can I zero choice- radio buttons column (eg. set all radio buttons to false)??

Regards

Liron

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using a SPD workflow, you would just update the list item so that field equals nothing.

[image: Field Value]

In this example, I have a field called "Radio" and I'm just not selecting a value from the drop-down so it essentially clears it.

Note that this method will probably fail SPD workflow validation if your field is set to required, since clearing the value would violate that rule.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of workflow you are using, whether it is SPD or VS or something else, but you could try clearing the value of the field instead of setting it to anything.

Comment: From @liron's previous posts, I would guess a Nintex workflow. I would also guess that they won't respond in comments, or accept an answer...